# How force the iniState() all TabViews?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an application that has 2 observables on initiate from my two TabView but only the TabView that is opened it execute.

Widget from tab one

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    companyService = Provider.of<CompanyService>(context, listen: false);
    filterService = Provider.of<FilterService>(context, listen: false);
    companyService.loadFilter$.listen((value) {
      loadFilterListData(value);
    });
    super.initState();
  }
```

Widget from tab 2

```
companyService.loadFilter$.listen((value) {
  loadFilterProductData(value);
});
```

The second only work I move to the other tab

Answer (score 0):

since `initState` is called before the widget is mounted in the widget tree, you don't have any `context` to access at that time.

The first useful time you can use `context` is when `didChangeDependencies` gets called, which is called immediately after `initState` so it's safe to use it to do stuff before `build`.

Note that `didChangeDependencies` gets called every time a dependency changes, so you might want to write your code to get it executed just once, or stuff will be occasionally overwritten.

In your case, I'd do something like this:

```
@override
void didChangeDependencies() {
  super.didChangeDependencies();
  filterService ??= Provider.of<FilterService>(context, listen: false);
  if (companyService == null){
    companyService = Provider.of<CompanyService>(context, listen: false);
    companyService.loadFilter$.listen((value) {
      loadFilterListData(value);
    });
  }
}
```

Note that I've used the `??=` for the first assignment: it performs the assignment only if the left operand is `null`.

As for the second, an `if` was necessary since you have to do something more than assigning (listening).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for you response, but this code will execute on creation from the TabView? I want to create an initialization function for both TabViews, the problem is that this executes only if I click on the Tab

Comment: Sorry, I've missed that. Well, I believe that there's no way do force initState in a tab, since it makes sense that a tab is mounted and loaded only when necessary.